# Select Year only from database php (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a question, how to select year only from database in laravel?  I have in my database:

```
2015-07-02
2015-07-04
2015-08-06
```

I just want to select year ('2015')

I want to build in Laravel, my code is:

```
   $visit_time = DB::table('tr_visit')->join ('tm_child','tr_visit.Child_ID','=','tm_child.Child_ID')
       ->where('tr_visit.Child_ID', 'LIKE', '%' . $childName . '%')
       ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(tr_visit.Visit_Date)'))
       ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(tr_visit.Visit_Date)'))
       ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(Visit_Date)'))->distinct()->get();
```

Please help me, thank you

Comment: I don't know how Laravel works, but you get the full date and then `explode("-",$date)`

Comment: Seems correct.whats wrong with your code?

Comment: @b0s3 it's not work.. we should use DB::raw

Comment: what's the output of above query?

Comment: @VMcreator  the output: 2015-07-02 2015-08-04

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
->selectRaw('YEAR(Visit_Date)')
```

And using Eloquent

```
$visit_time = Tr_visit::join('tm_child', 'tr_visit.Child_ID', '=', 'tm_child.Child_ID')
->where('tr_visit.Child_ID', 'like', '%' . $childName . '%')
->groupBy(['date', 'month'])
->selectRaw('YEAR(tr_visit.Visit_Date) as date, MONTH(tr_visit.Visit_Date) as month')
->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

edit

```
->select(DB::raw('YEAR(tr_visit.Visit_Date)'))
```

Comment: how to pass $visit_time [->select(DB::raw('YEAR(tr_visit.Visit_Date)')) ]to view?